# Difference between fit, transform and fit_transform

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When you import the library `from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler`, there you have three methods: `fit`, `transform`, and `fit_transform`.

When you should apply `fit` and `transform` individually and when at the same time? Could you explain it through an example to clarify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You `fit` your training data, to generalize a model.
2. Then you can apply that model, to any other data to get the prediction. This is like you `transform` the test data to prediction.
3. if you do `fit_transform`, you are generalizing a model using training data, and get the result of the model over your training data.